# Encoding/Decoding "&" in a URL parameter

Tags: javascript

Here is a string which I'm encoding in JavaScript using `encodeURI`

Original String - copyright=Copyright © 2003

This is the encoded String - Copyright%20%C2%A9%202003

I'm passing this text with a link like `www://abc.com?param=Copyright%20%C2%A9%202003` which in turn opens a javascript popup window.

But when I decode this string in the pop up page, in IE10 it comes like "Copyright Â© 2003" where as across Chrome & Firefox it shows like "Copyright © 2003".

I understand IE does not display this special character © properly and for that we need to use `"&copy"`. But somehow I can't send `"&copy"` as the parameter as  it treats `"&copy"` as a new parameter itself as it starts with `"&"`

Could you please let me know how to properly encode/decode this text correctly across IE using javascript.

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

Comment: A person usually needs `encodeURIComponent` instead of `encodeURI`, e.g., `&` and `=` are ok in a URI, but will cause problems if you are concatenating a string with them in a component as they may be interpreted as new parameters.

Comment: I don't want to encode "www.abc.com" rather I want only to encode the parameter and that's why I 'm encoding this using encodeURI.

Comment: then you should use `encodeURIComponent`--that's the reason for it...

Comment: and then you won't have your problem...

Comment: I wouldn't think IE has a problem with directly using Unicode either, as long as the file is saved as UTF-8 and contains a proper meta directive.

Answer (score 1):

Using HTML entities like `&copy;` is only valid for escaping special characters inside HTML. It is not useful to send it as parameter of a URL.

The problem you have seems to be that the browser is using an UTF-8 encoding to store strings and the `©` character is stored as a 2 byte sequence with is encoded as `%C2%A9` in the URL. The page that decodes the URL doesn't seem to use UTF-8 and decodes the 2 bytes as 2 separate characters `Â©`.

As long as you don't tell the browser which character set to use, it can choose whatever it thinks is the best option. Firefox and Chrome seem to prefer UTF-8 and encode and decode the string correctly. Internet Explorer 10 seems to choose a different character set in each of the pages.

You should make sure that all pages have a

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

tag in the HTML header. This will usually tell the browser which charset to use for strings and should fix the problem with encoding and decoding of non-ASCII characters in URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `encodeURIComponent` on the parameter you send (and `decodeURIComponent` on the other end) along with the proper meta tag (below is the simpler yet still backward-compatible and HTML5-friendly way) and document encoding. This will escape things like `&` and `=` which can otherwise get treated like parameter separators.

Here's an IE10 and FF27-tested demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

<script>

var testString = '\u00a9'; // Show the copyright symbol by default
              // though you can test with "&" and "=" in here as well
var loc = window.location.href;
if (loc.indexOf('param=') === -1) { // Add the param if not present
    window.location += '?param=' + encodeURIComponent(testString);
}

// Show the symbol after the param (in a safe manner).
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
    decodeURIComponent(loc.replace(/.*?\?param=/, ''))
));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```